# Is there a shortcut for intellij Idea for go to next method in the file for Mac?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know there is one for VS <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd>/<kbd>up arrow</kbd>. I couldn't find one for Intellij though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is. <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> is the shortcut for this. My setup is <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down/Up arrow</kbd> (may work for you too). Down/Up for next/previous method.

You may check it by

`settings` -> `keymap` -> `navigate` -> `navigate in file` -> `next method`

Answer (score 7):

It's now `shift` + `^` + `up arrow`/`down arrow`